# Admob&Internet in Android Application

Tags: android, admob

*First of all, i m using test device for testing. I have no real device.

*I implement admob in my app. I wonder if the user rejects internet connection, will application be opened with showing no advertisement on screen or application will never be opened?

*By the way, i can't test internet connection permission because test device has aldready connected internet via my pc connection so there is no permission asking from device. Is there any disable or something for testing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if the user rejects internet connection, will application be
>   opened with showing no advertisement on screen or application will
>   never be opened?

You mean if the device is offline?
In that case the application will open without showing any ad.

> By the way, i can't test internet connection permission because test
>   device has aldready connected internet via my pc connection so there
>   is no permission asking from device.

The permission is required in any case

Comment: Hmm there is no notification(use internet or not) while i m opening application on virtual device. Is there a problem in my manifest file?        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> these are in the manifest tag.

Comment: There is never any notification if you install an application directly no matter if its on the emulator or a real device.

Comment: I understand. If i publish application on market, people who downloads into device get a notifcation about use internet or not or download in sd card. Is it? - I'm trying to publish it without errors. Therefore, i have a one more question here: How the admob system works? For example, if user clicks the advertisement, publishers earn money or when the application is opened and activity which is included ads shows on screen without clicking advertisements by users.

Comment: Yes and yes admob pays per click.